# How to easily locate photo opened in Windows 8.1 Photo App

Tags: windows-8.1, photos, windows-photo-gallery

**Short story**

Where on disk is the photo I'm looking at?

---

**tldr;**

My daughter is scrolling through all photo's we have using the Windows 8.1 Photo App. She has a photo **maximized** on screen and is using the left/right arrow keys to select a previous/next one.

When she finds a photo she likes, she asks me to save it to an USB drive and this is where things gets weird: *"I can't find an easy way to open or even get the file location of the currently maximized photo"*

**My current workflow to copy the selected photo is to:**

- Click on the photo
- Select *Open with*
- Choose *another* application *(Paint for example)*
- Go to *File* → *Save as* to find the file location.
- Go to the file location and copy the photo to an USB drive.

This is crazy, there should be a far easier way to do this but unless I'm missing something really obvious, I can't for the life of me find it?

Comment: From [Photos app for Windows help FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/photos-app-faq): "You can use the Photos app to view or edit photos and videos *in your Pictures library and on OneDrive*"

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - My pictures library contains 20.000+ photo's scattered *(organized)* in a multitude of folders *(yyyy\yyyy-mm-dd)*. I know where the root is but I want to know where the photo I'm looking at is.

Comment: Valuable information you should include in your question. ;)

Comment: 'My daughter is scrolling through all photo's we have...' Thoght this was going to go a completely different direction...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - done :)

Comment: @EBGreen Me too, are we sick? ;)

Comment: @EBGreen - I see now how that can get misinterpreted but rest assured, it's all decent :) Feel free to edit the question to remove all doubt *(English is not my native language)*.

Comment: No edit needed, it's us, not you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no official way to do this built-in to the Photos app. This solution should at least save you some time. Create a text file with the following contents:

```
@if not [%1]==[] explorer %~dp1
```

Save this file and then change the file extension to `.bat`. For example, if the original file name was `OpenDirectory.txt`, change it to `OpenDirectory.bat`. Place this file in a location where it can permanently reside. This batch file opens the folder that contains the file that is passed to it as a command-line argument. It should look like this:

[image: file icon][image: file contents]

Then, open a photo in the Windows 8 photos app. Choose the "Open with" option.

[image: Open with]

Uncheck the box that says "Use this app for all .JPG files". Then choose "More options".

[image: More options]

Scroll all the way to the bottom and choose "Look for another app on this PC".

[image: Look for another app on this PC]

Now browse to the location where you saved the `OpenDirectory.bat` file. Select it. The folder containing the image should open.In the future, `OpenDirectory.bat` should appear as an option in your "Open with" list:

[image: OpenDirectory.bat]

Don't forget to always uncheck the "Use this app for all .JPG files" box.

Comment: Nice and quite a few clicks shorter than going through another app but it amazes *(and frustrates)* me that there's no easier solution.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I agree. Windows 8 full screen apps sacrifice functionality in favor of simplicity.